my play button doesn't displaying on hover
i'm making a music streaming website and i want that the play button appears when i hovers a song. why it is not working? why is the css section that is overriding the others(they are all meant to be used for different parts) (i used fontawesome icons)


.play-btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
}

.containera:hover .play-btn {
  opacity: 1;
}

.play-btn a:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.sameMovieCard:hover .play-btn_songpost {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}

#songlist .play-btn {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s ease;
}
<div class="sameMovieCard">
  <div class="container_songpost">
    <img src="..." id="A_..." />
    <div class="overlay_songpost"></div>
    <div class="play-btn_songpost">
      <a class="play-btn" data-song-url="..." id="..." onclick="playSong(this)">
        <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Let me understand, when you hover the image you want to see the icon to play?

yes, exactly...

Frederico, it is not very clear what you want. Do you want to show the icon on hover and then play the music when clicking on it?  Pls update your code with your javascript if so with function playSong

yes it's like this but the problem is css, because if i click on the image the song is played

Can't you adjust with display property?
.play-btn {
  display: none;
}
.container_songpost:hover .play-btn{
  display: block;
}

